# Convert ibatis to mybatis

Tags: ant, ibatis, mybatis

I have run [ibatis2mybatis tool](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/DocUpgrade3) to convert ibatis to mybatis and I get an error:

> [xslt] Transforming into D:\Program Files\ibatis2mybatis\destination
>
> [xslt] Processing D:\Program Files\ibatis2mybatis\source\SqlMapConfig.xml to D:\Program Files\ibatis2mybatis\destin
>   ation\SqlMapConfig.xml
>
> [xslt] Loading stylesheet D:\Program Files\ibatis2mybatis\migrate.xslt
>
> [xslt] : Error! The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-forme
>   d.
>
> [xslt] : Error! com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
>
> [xslt] Failed to process null

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
  PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<!-- iBATIS mapping configuration  -->
<sqlMapConfig>
<settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>

<transactionManager type="JDBC">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
        <property name="x" />
        <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="x" />
        <property name="JDBC.Username" value="x" /> 
        <property name="JDBC.Password" value="x" />
        <!--<property name="JDBC.Username" value="x" />
        <property name="JDBC.Password" value="x" />-->
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>


<sqlMap resource="maps/DatabaseResolve.xml"/>
<sqlMap resource="maps/DatabaseModify.xml"/>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that if you remove your old DOCTYPE declaration the ANT build works.
But that makes no sense for me as I have to grab every XML file.